# MakeArray from stack variables using idapython

Tags: ida, idapython

I want to `MakeArray()` to stack variables which can be done with IDA like so:

[image: MakeArray to stack variables]

> MakeArray() Create an array.
>
> ea      - linear address
>
> nitems  - size of array in items
>
> This function will create an array of the items with the same type as
>
> the type of the item at 'ea'. If the byte at 'ea' is undefined, then
>
> this function will create an array of bytes. How can I do that?
>   Thanks.

`MakeArray()`  works only on linear address and not on stack variables as shown above.

How can it be done?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember you need to modify stack frame of the function in order to achieve your goal.

Stack frame in IDA is represented by the structure which has its own id and type. 
In order to get this structure id you need you can use [idc.get_frame_id](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc-module.html#get_frame_id)
In order to get structure itself in newer API (IDA 7.0 + if I remember it correctly) you can use [ida_frame.get_frame](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_frame-module.html#get_frame)

After getting either frame id or the structure, you can modify it.

If you are working with structure, you can modify it with functions from module [ida_struct](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/toc-ida_struct-module.html).

If you are working with structure ID, you can use [idc.add_struc_member](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc-module.html#add_struc_member).

You'll probably need to delete members of the frame occupying the required space first.

Comment: `MakeArray()` needs an `ea` as parameter, can it work on structure? how can I extract the ea of a struct variable?

Comment: @Kinetics332: use the struct member id as ea

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me on IDA 7.2:

1. Get the frame id and confirm it's sane.

```
Python> frame_id = get_frame_id(get_name_ea(BADADDR, 'sub_5450'))
Python> print(list(StructMembers(frame_id)))
[(0L, 'var_18', 8L), (12L, 'var_C', 4L), (24L, ' r', 8L)]
```

2. Get the existing variable id.

```
Python> var_id = get_member_id(frame_id, 12)
```

If I needed a new variable, I would have used `add_struc_member(frame_id, 'var_name', var_offset, FF_DATA | FF_BYTE, -1, 1)` first.

3. Use `apply_type` in order to turn the variable into an array.

```
Python> apply_type(var_id, parse_decl('int[2]', 0))
True
```

Somehow `MakeArray` did not work:

```
Python> MakeArray(var_id, 2)
False
```